# Number of consectuive sums error?

Tags: java, optimization

I am working on a program that takes an integer and finds the number of combinations of consecutive sums that the integer has:

> The number 13 can be expressed as a sum of consecutive positive
>   integers 6 + 7. Fourteen can be expressed as 2 + 3 + 4 + 5, also a sum
>   of consecutive positive integers. Some numbers can be expressed as a
>   sum of consecutive positive integers in more than one way. For
>   example, 25 is 12 + 13 and is also 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7.

I researched and read that it's the number of odd factors minus one. So I wrote a program that finds the number of odd factors and my answer is still wrong in certain cases. Any insight?

Code seems to work fine but there is a crash due to Timeout which is probably due to optimization error.

The constraints for possible input size is 
1 to 10^(12)

The code below is copied from [alfasin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46751658/1057429) below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


  static long consecutive(long num) {
    while (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2;
    return  consecutiveHelper(num);
}

public static long consecutiveHelper(long num) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(3, (num / 2)).parallel().filter(x -> x % 2 != 0).map(fn -> (num % fn == 0) ? 1 : 0).sum();
}
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final String fileName = System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH");
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        if (fileName != null) {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        }
        else {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        }

        int res;
        long num;
        num = Long.parseLong(in.nextLine().trim());

        res = consecutive(num);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(res));
        bw.newLine();

        bw.close();
    }
}
```

This is what i currently have

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156783/discussion-on-question-by-ron-baker-number-of-consectuive-sums-error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### As the post i answered to was duplicate, I copied my answer here as well.
Let's try to find a pseudo-optimized method to resolve your problem :

What you need to do is to **decompose your number in prime factors**.

For example, if you take **1200** :

`1200 = 2*2*2*2*3*5*5 = 1 * 2^4 * 3^1 * 5^2`

You can then analyze **how you could get odd factors with those prime factors**. A quick analyze will tell you that :

- **odd * odd = odd**
- odd * even = even
- even * even = even

With that in mind, let's find all the factors we get with **odd * odd** :

- 1 * 1 = 1
- 3 * 1 = 3
- 5 * 1 = 5
- 5 * 3 = 15
- 5 * 5 = 25
- 5 * 5 * 3 = 75

A quick way to find these combinations without writing them all is the "**plus 1 method**" : add 1 to the number of occurences of each prime odd factor, and **multiply them together** :

We found that `1200 = 1 * 2^4 * 3^1 * 5^2`, so we can do :

- ("number of 3" + 1) ("number of 5" + 1) = `(1 + 1) ( 2 + 1) = 6`

**There are 6 odd factors for the number 1200, and as you stated, remove 1 from that number to get the number of combinations of consecutive sums that 1200 has :**

- **6 - 1 = 5** *<-- woohoo ! finally got the result !*

---

Now, let's look at the code. **What we want to have is a Map, the keys being the prime factors and the values being the number of their occurences** :

```
/*
    If number is odd,
    find the number in the keys and add 1 to its value.
    If the number is not in the keys, add it with value = 1.
 */
public static void addValue(Map<Integer, Integer> factors, int i) {
    if(i % 2 != 0) {
        int count = factors.containsKey(i) ? factors.get(i) : 0;
        factors.put(i, ++count);
    }
}

/*
    Classic algorithm to find prime numbers
 */
public static Map<Integer, Integer> oddPrimeFactors(int number) {
    int n = number;
    Map<Integer, Integer> factors = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            addValue(factors, i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if(n > 1) addValue(factors, n);
    return factors;
}
```

With that, let's try to print what the map contains for number **1200** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1200;

    System.out.println(oddPrimeFactors(n));
}
```

```
$n : {3=1, 5=2}
```

Good ! Now let's finish the program **with the method we developed before** :

```
public static int combinations = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1200;

    oddPrimeFactors(n).forEach((key, value) -> combinations *= (value + 1));
    combinations--;

    System.out.println(combinations);
}
```

```
$combinations = 5
```

Finished ! feel free to ask if you did not understand something !
Note : I tried my program with the max value Integer can handle and it took less than one second for my program to proceed, which seems pretty fast to me. It could probably be faster though, it's up to you to find the most optimized version of this code !

Comment: hey are you there

Comment: yes, the other post was duplicate so I posted here. You can accept the answer at the left if it solved your problem. You said you'd ask a question but you didnt do so

Comment: oh i asked it in the other post by accident sorry

Comment: i saw it now, but what's the problem with longs ? just replace int by long and Integer by Long

Answer (score 0):

Here are the optimizations that we discussed in the comments section, see comments as markers:

```
static int consecutive(long num) {
    while (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2; // 1st opt.
    return  consecutiveHelper(num)-1;
}

public static int consecutiveHelper(long num) {
    long factorNumber = 1;
    int count = 0;

    while(factorNumber <= num / 2) { // 2nd opt.
        if(num % factorNumber == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        factorNumber += 2; // 3rd opt.
    }
    if (num % 2 != 0) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to reduce ~50% runtime for big-numbers (10^12) by using Java 8 Stream interface and running in parallel:

```
static long consecutive(long num) {
    while (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2;
    return  consecutiveHelper(num);
}

public static long consecutiveHelper(long num) {
    return LongStream
        .rangeClosed(3, (num / 2))
        .parallel()
        .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
        .map(fn -> (num % fn == 0) ? 1 : 0)
        .sum();
}
```

That said, parallel will be more expensive when you're dealing with smaller numbers. If you want your answer to be optimal you should use both methods:  for smaller numbers use the first and for large numbers use the latter.

Comment: dang still timeout

Comment: well it passed one more test case then last time

Comment: check out the 2nd opt. again

Comment: well now it fails for 15

Comment: didnt mean to post twice btw

Comment: no worries. There might be additional optimizations that could be applied but I can't come up with any at the moment, I'll update it tomorrow if I'll think of anything that I can add.

Comment: Morning @RonBaker it seems that there is no way to reduce the amount of computation in magnitude... for more details, read: [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46755710/optimization-causes-timeout

Comment: I sent you it as a reference not to mark as duplicate -_-

Comment: @RonBaker posting the same question more than once considered as spamming here, if you'll keep doing it one of the moderators might close your account, please stop doing it.

Comment: there seems to be an issue when I try it says it doesn't know what longstream is

Comment: You should import it

Comment: Im using java.util.stream

Comment: `import java.util.stream.LongStream; `

Comment: Please add the explicit import and try again. I'm away from my computer right now, can't help more than that...

Comment: I still get error even though i seemingly have everything

Comment: You totally ignored the part I said you should run in parallel only for big numbers...

Comment: Um how would i distinguish im lost do i hard code a cut off point where numbers are no longer considered small