# optimization causes timeout?

Tags: java, optimization

I am working on a program that takes an integer and finds the number of combinations of consecutive sums that the integer has:

> The number 13 can be expressed as a sum of consecutive positive
>   integers 6 + 7. Fourteen can be expressed as 2 + 3 + 4 + 5, also a sum
>   of consecutive positive integers. Some numbers can be expressed as a
>   sum of consecutive positive integers in more than one way. For
>   example, 25 is 12 + 13 and is also 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7.

I researched and read that it's the number of odd factors minus one. So I wrote a program that finds the number of odd factors and my answer is still wrong in certain cases. Any insight?

Code seems to work fine but there is a crash due to Timeout which is probably due to optimization error.

The constraints for possible input size is 
1 to 10^(12)

```
static int consecutive(long num) {
    while (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2; // 1st opt.
    return  consecutiveHelper(num)-1;
}

public static int consecutiveHelper(long num) {
    long factorNumber = 1;
    int count = 0;

    while(factorNumber <= num / 2) { // 2nd opt.
        if(num % factorNumber == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        factorNumber += 2; // 3rd opt.
    }
    if (num % 2 != 0) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's try to find a pseudo-optimized method to resolve your problem :

What you need to do is to **decompose your number in prime factors**.

For example, if you take **1200** :

`1200 = 2*2*2*2*3*5*5 = 1 * 2^4 * 3^1 * 5^2`

You can then analyze **how you could get odd factors with those prime factors**. A quick analyze will tell you that :

- **odd * odd = odd**
- odd * even = even
- even * even = even

With that in mind, let's find all the factors we get with **odd * odd** :

- 1 * 1 = 1
- 3 * 1 = 3
- 5 * 1 = 5
- 5 * 3 = 15
- 5 * 5 = 25
- 5 * 5 * 3 = 75

A quick way to find these combinations without writing them all is the "**plus 1 method**" : add 1 to the number of occurences of each prime odd factor, and **multiply them together** :

We found that `1200 = 1 * 2^4 * 3^1 * 5^2`, so we can do :

- ("number of 3" + 1) ("number of 5" + 1) = `(1 + 1) ( 2 + 1) = 6`

**There are 6 odd factors for the number 1200, and as you stated, remove 1 from that number to get the number of combinations of consecutive sums that 1200 has :**

- **6 - 1 = 5** *<-- woohoo ! finally got the result !*

---

Now, let's look at the code. **What we want to have is a Map, the keys being the prime factors and the values being the number of their occurences** :

```
/*
    If number is odd,
    find the number in the keys and add 1 to its value.
    If the number is not in the keys, add it with value = 1.
 */
public static void addValue(Map<Integer, Integer> factors, int i) {
    if(i % 2 != 0) {
        int count = factors.containsKey(i) ? factors.get(i) : 0;
        factors.put(i, ++count);
    }
}

/*
    Classic algorithm to find prime numbers
 */
public static Map<Integer, Integer> oddPrimeFactors(int number) {
    int n = number;
    Map<Integer, Integer> factors = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            addValue(factors, i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if(n > 1) addValue(factors, n);
    return factors;
}
```

With that, let's try to print what the map contains for number **1200** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1200;

    System.out.println(oddPrimeFactors(n));
}
```

```
$n : {3=1, 5=2}
```

Good ! Now let's finish the program **with the method we developed before** :

```
public static int combinations = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1200;

    oddPrimeFactors(n).forEach((key, value) -> combinations *= (value + 1));
    combinations--;

    System.out.println(combinations);
}
```

```
$combinations = 5
```

Finished ! feel free to ask if you did not understand something !
Note : I tried my program with the max value Integer can handle and it took less than one second for my program to proceed, which seems pretty fast to me. It could probably be faster though, it's up to you to find the most optimized version of this code !

Comment: Wow this is a very detailed answer.  Thanks

Comment: One question though

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you. What is your question ?

Comment: So the function i have works with longs not ints...can i maybe see a version that works with longs please